# Could not find version google-assistant-library Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, voice, google-assistant-sdk

I am currently trying to install `google-assistant-library`via Python pip on my raspberry pi 1 Model B using ssh. But I keep running into this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   google-assistant-library (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for google-assistant-library

After running this command:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install google-assistant-libary
```

Can anyone please assist me?

Answer (score 1):

The library is written in Python and **supports devices with linux-armv7l architectures (like the Raspberry Pi 3 B).**

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample

Comment: Yes I realize that google-assistant-libary runs on linux-armv7I but isn't the Raspberry Pi 3 running ARMv8. Surely if it works on the ARMv8 it might be possible to port it to ARMV6?

Comment: look there: https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/6cha7d/has_anyone_tried_putting_the_google_assistant_api/

Comment: Thanks for the link. You are totally correct. I guess all I need to do now is just convince Google to release an ARMV6 version. :)

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head over this for a while.. The problem was so simple.

The misspelling of library

I did the same, spelling it 'libary' so make sure its 'lib*r*ary'

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
python -m pip install google-assistant-library==1.0.1
```